# How to validate what a REST Service expects to receive in JSON (JSONArray or JSONObject)

Tags: java, json, rest, format

For example right now all my rest methods are working with JSONObjects, so at the client I send String JSONObject for the petitions, but what if I had one of those methods expecting an JSONArray String, in my case I have a method that generates JSONObject String with a HashMap of parameters like this:

```
public JsonObject generarJSON(HashMap map) throws MalformedURLException {
    JsonObject json = new JsonObject();

    for (Object key : map.keySet()) {
        if (map.get(key) instanceof List) {
            JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
            json.add(key.toString(), parser.parse((map.get(key).toString())));
        } else {
            json.addProperty(key.toString(), map.get(key).toString());
        }
    }

    return json;
}
```

And here is the consume of the rest services:
notice that I use the above method to write to the service, it works because all my services are expecting JSONObject but what if there was one of them that expected JSONArray, how can I validate if that url needs a JSONArray format or JSONObject format? I hope you guys understand what Im trying to do.

```
try {

                // Parametro, Properties, Ruta quemada
                URL url = new URL("http://10.11.6.68:8280/" + configApp.getString("rutaService") + contexto);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                JsonObject requestJson = new JsonObject();
                requestJson = generarJSON(parametros);
                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                os.write(requestJson.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
                os.close();
                if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP Error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
                }

                InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);

                while ((cadenaLectura = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    cadenaJSON = cadenaJSON.concat(cadenaLectura);

                }
                conn.disconnect();
                if (esJSONArray(cadenaJSON)) {
                    System.out.println("PARAMETROS Y JSON ARRAY");
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(cadenaJSON);
                    return jsonArray.toString();
                } else if (esJSONObject(cadenaJSON)) {
                    System.out.println("PARAMETROS Y JSON OBJECT");
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(cadenaJSON);
                    return json.toString();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception in NetClientGet:- " + e);
            }
```

for example this is one of my methods that receive that json:

```
@POST
    @Path("/buscarUrlCerberusPorIp")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String buscarUrlCerberus(String data) {
        logger.info("Se ejecuta el servicio buscar la URL de Cerberus por Ip");
        JsonObject gson = new JsonObject();

        try {

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
            String ipCliente = json.getString("ipCliente");
            String urlCerberus = businessDelegateServiciosLocal.buscarUrlCerberus(ipCliente);
            gson.addProperty("ruta", urlCerberus);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info("ERROR: " + e);
            return null;
        }
        return gson.toString();
    }
```

But what if I had one like this one:

```
@POST
@Path("/prueba")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public PruebaJSON prueba(String data) {

    try {

        JSONArray json = new JSONArray(data);
        Gson convertir = new GsonBuilder().create();
        PruebaJSON pruebaJson = convertir.fromJson(json.get(0).toString(), PruebaJSON.class);

        return pruebaJson;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error " + e);
        return null;
    }

}
```

notice that this one is expecting JSONArray String

Comment: I was thinking that maybe I should add a validation on the PruebaJSON method, that validates if the string is a JSONArray or a JSONObject, and according to that do something? or is there another way

Comment: When you are preparing the `JSONArray` object out of `data` string object, it will throw exception there only, in case, data is not carrying a valid string representation of the JSON Array object. if this lines gets executed successfully, string is valid.
`JSONArray json = new JSONArray(data);`